# Create subdomain dynamically in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-ajax, subdomain

I want to create a sub-domain dynamically using C#.

e.g., The domain name is `www.example.com`. How would I create a country sub domain dynamically based on region. For instance, I want to add India as the sub-domain using C# `www.india.example.com`.

Answer (score 1):

This is simples alternative to do this:

- http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/20/ASPNET-MVC-Domain-Routing.aspx
- http://lukesampson.com/post/303245177/subdomains-for-a-single-application-with-asp-net-mvc