# Create Subdomain into the main domain by name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have to create a website that contains the name of the user in the domain.

For example, I have site like shop.com, now when any user is register with our site then he gets his login credentials to our site. When he logins inthe url is changed something like "abc.shop.com". The abc is the name of user I suppose.

So my question is how we can achieve this? Is there any API we use or any example that can help me?

Comment: When you say change the URL do you mean how it's displayed in their browser?

Comment: See this post, it has a couple of articles on the subject. [Create subdomain dynamically in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570187/create-subdomain-dynamically-in-asp-net)